# Unintended offset when printing atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, printing, atlas

I'm printing a series of maps using the Atlas feature in QGIS.  Everything is working fine, except when I print the atlas all of the elements are offset from where they are in the composer.
I can work around by printing the atlas, then gaming the position so the elements  show up where I want, but it takes a bit of monkeying that shouldn't be necessary.
If I use the regular "Export as PDF" button, I get a copy of the current atlas page with everything aligned appropriately.  Using the "export Atlas as images also produces correctly aligned images, but then need to be converted and assembled into a book.

[image: Export as pdf prints correctly]

But when I print, which I need to do to get the entire atlas, and not just the current page, all of the map elements appear shifted down and to the right by about 1/3 inch.

[image: Elements are shifted when I print the same layout through the Atlas feature]

It's a little difficult to see the offset in the images because of the white page on white background, but if you look closely, the map elements are all shifted down and to the right, and as a consequence, the margins are not even.

By measuring the shift and adjusting the positions, I can get things close, but this is really clunky, and doesn't produce as nice of results as I can get by specifying positions and sizes of the elements.

How can I force the atlas to print like it's displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if I use the "Export Atlas to PDF" function, but requires a lot of free space on the drive. As a side benefit the Export Atlas function seems to complete a little faster.

Comment: Meta- Since I answered my own question, I'm not sure if it would be better to delete the post or leave it up.

Comment: Self-answering is perfectly legitimate. When someone comes along with the same issue, your answer will be just as helpful as if someone else had written it.